# If I have a 500 Internal Server Error should I contact my web hosting or domain registrar?

Tags: domains, http-code-500

Who are you supposed to contact when you see a *HTTP 500* error?

Comment: Probably your web developer

Answer (score 2):

Server errors are just that - errors that occurred with your web hosting server. You can Google error codes for an idea of what's going on, for example:  [Error 500](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html)

Since you're able to reach the domain, it's not an issue for the domain registrar - contact your web hosting company's support team for help.

If you have access to your web hosting server logs (look under the directory "logs" using FTP or a Filemanager script), you can review the error log for additional information as to what occurred.